Can the layer InstanceNormalization fuse with convolution?
Can the layer InstanceNormalization fuse with Convolution ?
scale = 1 and B = 0
enter image description here
InstanceNormalization
Carries out instance normalization as described in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08022.
y = scale * (x - mean) / sqrt(variance + epsilon) + B, where mean and variance are computed per instance per channel.
